# Submit active form on li element click Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, forms, yii2

I have an `ActiveForm` and I am trying to submit it by clicking one of the `li` elements. Tried with javascript but what I get is `form is not defined`.

The purpose is to send the letter through `$_GET` and make a search in the controller to find all results in the database table that starts with the clicked letter.

this is my form:

```
<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
                            'id' => 'charsForm',
                            'action' => '#',
                            'method' => 'get',
                            'options' => ['data-pjax' => true, 'onsubmit' => 'return pjaxFilterLetters();', 'id' => 'filter-group2'],
                        ]) ?>
                        <div class="authors-filter">
                            <ul class="letters">
                            <?php foreach ($array_in_use as $char){
                                echo '<li onclick="form.submit()">' . $char . '</li>';
                            } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

`$array_in_use` is just an array with all the letters.
And some jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var letters = $('.letter').find('li');
    var form = $("#charsForm");
    letters.on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

I am declaring the variable `form` here but guess this is not the right way.

How should i submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your click event to:

```
 var letters = $('.letters').find('li');
 var form = $("#charsForm");
 letters.on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');//this will disappear when the page is refreshed after the submit 
        form.submit();
    });
```

remove the onclick attribute

Answer (score 1):

There's seems to be a typo within the class definitions (letters <-> letter): `<ul class="letters">` <-> `var letters = $('.letter').find('li');`

Change

```
echo '<li onclick="form.submit()">' . $char . '</li>';
```

to

```
echo '<li>' . $char . '</li>';
```

Then submit the form in the javascript on click to a `li` element.

```
$(function(){
    var letters = $('.letters').find('li');
    var form = $("#charsForm");
    letters.on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        form.submit();
    });
});
```